# Is it possible to decrypt Bcrypt encryption?

Tags: bcrypt

I do have password that has been encrypted with Bcrypt and the salt . Is it possible if I want to decrypt the password into normal text ?

Comment: No, there is no way to get the original string without exhaustively trying all possible inputs. This is the entire point of password hashes like bcrypt.

Answer (score 10):

`bcrypt` is not an encryption function, it's a password **hashing** function, [relying on Blowfish's key scheduling, not its encryption](https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/). Hashing are mathematical one-way functions, meaning there is no* way to reverse the output string to get the input string.

**of course only Siths deal in absolutes and there are a few attacks against hashes. But none of them are "reversing" the hashing, AFAIK.*